# TensorFlow model converter to tflite

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I only have the model training file, in the folder there are two folders with the name: "assets" and "variables"; And the files "keras_metadata.pb" and "saved_model.pb", how can I convert this model to tflite

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the path to the whole directory to TFLiteConverter

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Convert the model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir) # path to the SavedModel directory
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

See https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/convert/convert_models#convert_a_savedmodel_recommended_